# Extrair datas de campo de texto livre

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estou executando uma consulta em uma view, porém um de seus campos é texto, neste campo o pode usuário informa uma data(xx/xx/xxxx) como também qualquer outra informação de tipo texto. Gostaria de saber como posso retornar apenas os registros que conseguir converter para data ou como posso tratar o erro abaixo, que ocorre quando tento converter o campo no tipo que preciso?

> Erro: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

consulta que estou fazendo:

```
SELECT 
    V.CAMPO1, 
    V.CAMPO1, 
    V.CAMPO1,  
    V.CAMPO_CHAR_DATA, 

CASE WHEN RTRIM(V.CAMPO_CHAR_DATA) <> '' THEN       
    CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(V.CAMPO_CHAR_DATA, ),103)
    ELSE '2017-01-01 00:00:00' 
END AS CAMPO_CHAR_DATA 

FROM VIEW_TESTE V
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma boa solução seria utilizar expressões regulares. Se bem me lembro elas são suportadas nativamente nas versões mais recentes do SQL Server, mas você especificou a versão 2008.

Nessa versão, para utilizar expressões regulares, você precisa criar uma função própria, e nessa função deve utilizar algum componente externo. O Windows vem com alguns. [Desta página](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/khen1234/2005/05/11/regular-expressions-in-t-sql/) eu retirei um exemplo de uma função que pode ajudar:

```
CREATE FUNCTION    
dbo.fn_regex(@pattern varchar(255), @matchstring varchar(8000))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @obj int
    declare @res int
    declare @match bit
    set @match=0
    exec @res=sp_OACreate 'VBScript.RegExp',@obj OUT
    IF (@res <> 0) BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END
    exec @res=sp_OASetProperty @obj, 'Pattern', @pattern
    IF (@res <> 0) BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END
    exec @res=sp_OASetProperty @obj, 'IgnoreCase', 1
    IF (@res <> 0) BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END
    exec @res=sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Test',@match OUT, @matchstring
    IF (@res <> 0) BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END
    exec @res=sp_OADestroy @obj
    return @match
END
GO
```

Para utilizar:

```
SELECT V.CAMPO1, V.CAMPO2 -- etc, etc
FROM VIEW_TESTE V
WHERE dbo.fn_regex('[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', V.CAMPO_CHAR_DATA) <> 0
```

(Ou outra expressão que lhe seja mais adequada).

Comment: Renan, obrigado pela resposta! Funcionou! \o/