# Extrair data em coluna de texto

Tags: sql, oracle

Existe outras formas **sem** usar `Regex` de extrair `data` de uma coluna de texto no `Oracle 19c`.

Até agora consegui utilizando `Regex` da seguinte forma:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(p.observacao, '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') as data
from pessoa p
```

Digamos que minha coluna observação tem a seguinte informação: 'teste 24/08/2020 abc'. Logo o resutado esperado é: 24/08/2020.

Algumas referências que pesquisei:

- [Extrair datas de campo de texto livre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239085/extrair-datas-de-campo-de-texto-livre)
- [Extract date from string and insert into field Microsoft SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769598/extract-date-from-string-and-insert-into-field-microsoft-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Sim, se na estrutura do back tiver um formato obrigatório, então é so formatar para o tipo data. exemplo: `to_date('10052020','dd/mm/yyyy')`

Comment: Se a data pode aparecer em qualquer parte do texto e não há um padrão claro (por exemplo, se há algum separador, ou um padrão de texto que aparece antes ou depois, etc), então acho que não tem muito jeito.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível. Desde que você saiba qual formado a data esteja.

Veja, primeiro encontre os dados que estejam de acordo com o seu padrão utilizando um filtro `LIKE`.

```
campo LIKE '%__/__/____%'
```

Neste caso buscamos qualquer valor que contenha algo no padrão `DD/MM/YYYY`. O `_` sinaliza para a consulta que pode ser qualquer valor.

Depois precisamos remover os lixos. Podemos fazer isso utilizando a função [translate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm).

"Traduzimos" tudo que está entre o que queremos, ou seja "0123456879/" para valores em branco.

```
translate(campo, '0123456789/',' ')
```

E o resultado, traduzimos novamente, utilizando o resultado da função acima.

```
translate(campo,(translate(campo, '0123456789/',' ')), ' ')
```

Podemos adicionar um `TRIM` para remover os espaços que sobraram e buscar pelos resultados que tenham apenas 10 caracteres, ou seja o tamanho do nosso padrão DD/MM/YYYY, ficando algo assim:

```
WITH dados AS (
  SELECT 'TESTE 01/01/2020' dt FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT '01/01/2020 TESTE' dt FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'TESTE 01/01TESTE/2020' dt FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'TESTE AA/01/2020' dt FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'TESTE AA/BB/2020' dt FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'TESTE 0E1/01/20E20' dt FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'TESTE 0E1/01/20' dt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TESTE 0E1/JAN/20' dt FROM DUAL union all 
  SELECT 'TESTE 2020/01/20' dt FROM DUAL 
)

,tratados as (
SELECT trim(translate(dt,(translate(dt, '0123456789/',' ')), ' ')) dt
  FROM dados 
 WHERE dt like '%__/__/____%'
    or dt like '%__/__/__%'
    or dt like '%__/___/__%'
    or dt like '%____/__/__%')

SELECT  CASE WHEN dt like '__/__/____' THEN 
         to_date(dt,'dd/mm/yyyy')
        WHEN dt like '__/__/__' THEN 
         to_date(dt,'dd/mm/yy') 
        WHEN dt like '__/___/__' THEN 
         to_date(dt,'dd/mon/yy') 
        WHEN dt like '____/__/__' THEN 
         to_date(dt,'yyyy/mm/dd') 
        END dt
  FROM tratados
 WHERE (dt like '%__/__/____%'
     or dt like '%__/__/__%'
     or dt like '%__/___/__%'
     or dt like '%____/__/__%')
```

Veja um exemplo rodando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1309d/65).

E assim vai... é só ir colocando os padrões...